# Java char recognition with OpenCV

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

i am trying to build an application that with a camera can recognize some numbers and letters from a board in front of the camera.

At moment i can detect faces, counters but i want to use ROI and Tess4j to recognize this live video.

Do you know any example of something like this?

My idea is that i have to analyze frame by frame and when i detect a char like '*' i make the full verification of the values

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String classifierName = null;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        classifierName = args[0];
    } else {
        URL url = new URL("https://raw.github.com/Itseez/opencv/2.4.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
        File file = Loader.extractResource(url, null, "classifier", ".xml");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        classifierName = file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    // Preload the opencv_objdetect module to work around a known bug.
    Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);

    // We can "cast" Pointer objects by instantiating a new object of the desired class.
    CvHaarClassifierCascade classifier = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(classifierName));
    if (classifier.isNull()) {
        System.err.println("Error loading classifier file \"" + classifierName + "\".");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // The available FrameGrabber classes include OpenCVFrameGrabber (opencv_videoio),
    // DC1394FrameGrabber, FlyCaptureFrameGrabber, OpenKinectFrameGrabber, OpenKinect2FrameGrabber,
    // RealSenseFrameGrabber, PS3EyeFrameGrabber, VideoInputFrameGrabber, and FFmpegFrameGrabber.
    FrameGrabber grabber = FrameGrabber.createDefault(0);
    grabber.start();

    // CanvasFrame, FrameGrabber, and FrameRecorder use Frame objects to communicate image data.
    // We need a FrameConverter to interface with other APIs (Android, Java 2D, or OpenCV).
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();

    // FAQ about IplImage and Mat objects from OpenCV:
    // - For custom raw processing of data, createBuffer() returns an NIO direct
    //   buffer wrapped around the memory pointed by imageData, and under Android we can
    //   also use that Buffer with Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer() and copyPixelsToBuffer().
    // - To get a BufferedImage from an IplImage, or vice versa, we can chain calls to
    //   Java2DFrameConverter and OpenCVFrameConverter, one after the other.
    // - Java2DFrameConverter also has static copy() methods that we can use to transfer
    //   data more directly between BufferedImage and IplImage or Mat via Frame objects.
    IplImage grabbedImage = converter.convert(grabber.grab());
    int width  = grabbedImage.width();
    int height = grabbedImage.height();
    IplImage grayImage    = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    IplImage rotatedImage = grabbedImage.clone();

    // Objects allocated with a create*() or clone() factory method are automatically released
    // by the garbage collector, but may still be explicitly released by calling release().
    // You shall NOT call cvReleaseImage(), cvReleaseMemStorage(), etc. on objects allocated this way.
    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

    // The OpenCVFrameRecorder class simply uses the CvVideoWriter of opencv_videoio,
    // but FFmpegFrameRecorder also exists as a more versatile alternative.
    FrameRecorder recorder = FrameRecorder.createDefault("output.avi", width, height);
    recorder.start();

    // CanvasFrame is a JFrame containing a Canvas component, which is hardware accelerated.
    // It can also switch into full-screen mode when called with a screenNumber.
    // We should also specify the relative monitor/camera response for proper gamma correction.
    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("Some Title", CanvasFrame.getDefaultGamma()/grabber.getGamma());

    // Let's create some random 3D rotation...
    CvMat randomR = CvMat.create(3, 3), randomAxis = CvMat.create(3, 1);
    // We can easily and efficiently access the elements of matrices and images
    // through an Indexer object with the set of get() and put() methods.
    DoubleIndexer Ridx = randomR.createIndexer(), axisIdx = randomAxis.createIndexer();
    axisIdx.put(0, (Math.random()-0.5)/4, (Math.random()-0.5)/4, (Math.random()-0.5)/4);
    cvRodrigues2(randomAxis, randomR, null);
    double f = (width + height)/2.0;  Ridx.put(0, 2, Ridx.get(0, 2)*f);
    Ridx.put(1, 2, Ridx.get(1, 2)*f);
    Ridx.put(2, 0, Ridx.get(2, 0)/f); Ridx.put(2, 1, Ridx.get(2, 1)/f);
    System.out.println(Ridx);

    // We can allocate native arrays using constructors taking an integer as argument.
    CvPoint hatPoints = new CvPoint(3);

    while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = converter.convert(grabber.grab())) != null) {
        cvClearMemStorage(storage);

        // Let's try to detect some faces! but we need a grayscale image...
        cvCvtColor(grabbedImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, classifier, storage,
                1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH);
        int total = faces.total();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
            int x = r.x(), y = r.y(), w = r.width(), h = r.height();
            cvRectangle(grabbedImage, cvPoint(x, y), cvPoint(x+w, y+h), CvScalar.RED, 1, CV_AA, 0);

            // To access or pass as argument the elements of a native array, call position() before.
            hatPoints.position(0).x(x-w/10)   .y(y-h/10);
            hatPoints.position(1).x(x+w*11/10).y(y-h/10);
            hatPoints.position(2).x(x+w/2)    .y(y-h/2);
            cvFillConvexPoly(grabbedImage, hatPoints.position(0), 3, CvScalar.GREEN, CV_AA, 0);
        }


        // Let's find some contours! but first some thresholding...
        cvThreshold(grayImage, grayImage, 64, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        // To check if an output argument is null we may call either isNull() or equals(null).
        CvSeq contour = new CvSeq(null);
        cvFindContours(grayImage, storage, contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),
                CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        while (contour != null && !contour.isNull()) {
            if (contour.elem_size() > 0) {
                CvSeq points = cvApproxPoly(contour, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class),
                        storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contour)*0.02, 0);
                cvDrawContours(grabbedImage, points, CvScalar.BLUE, CvScalar.BLUE, -1, 1, CV_AA);

            }

            contour = contour.h_next();
        }

        //TESS4J - se ahou os contornos, analisar conteúdo
        if(contour != null && !contour.isNull()) {
            IplImageToBufferedImage(grayImage);
            ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping
            instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");

            try {
                String result = instance.doOCR(IplImageToBufferedImage(grayImage));
                System.out.println(result);
            } catch (TesseractException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        cvWarpPerspective(grabbedImage, rotatedImage, randomR);

        Frame rotatedFrame = converter.convert(rotatedImage);
        frame.showImage(rotatedFrame);

        recorder.record(rotatedFrame);

    }
    frame.dispose();
    recorder.stop();
    grabber.stop();
}

public static BufferedImage IplImageToBufferedImage(IplImage src) {
    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage grabberConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
    Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
    Frame frame = grabberConverter.convert(src);
    return paintConverter.getBufferedImage(frame,1);
}

}
```

Comment: Why not just crop your grayImage?

Comment: im not knowing how to do that

Comment: `rectCrop = new Rect(x,y,width,height);`
 `Mat croppedImage = new Mat(image,rectCrop);`

Comment: i have a lot of conflicts, first my img is type IplImage, so Mat constructor does not work with it